# How to display 4 blocks of text in a tabular fashion?

Tags: html, css

I want to display the 4 blocks of text as below:

```
SmallText........................................SmallText
.................................................SmallText
VERY LONG DESCRIPTION SPANNING ACROSS.....................
MULTIPLE LINES...................................SmallText
```

I tried to fit these in tables but due to the longer description at the bottom left, the whole screen looks distorted. What is the best way to do it, considering the webpage is used across different devices?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="text">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>The Big Book</td>
                    <td>The Humming Tree</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>12, DownTown, CA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jehu Mulobo regularly captivates audiences as a lead guitarist and vocalist all over the world. His music demonstrates a range of shades and temperaments. The sound builds down to acoustic simplicity which draws influences from an electric range of genres from soukousse, blues, afrobeat, rumba and reggae.</td>
                    <td>Presented by DIG</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Are all blocks of text the same size?

Comment: Yeah, all are of same size.

Comment: use only one td where you want it to span over two columns... like this <td colspan="2">hello</td> .. can you share a printscreen? Preferable what you got and what you want... you can make it in paint lol

Comment: Here's a fiddle that uses divs, analogous to that of rogoro below http://jsfiddle.net/Az7LQ/. It's tough with styling the divs, so in this case, table my be a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting each text in separate div and add style to your divs. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RQ5/)

```
<div class = "title">Some Text......</div>
<div class = "description">VERY VERY LONG </div>
```